# Go fmt.Println display wrong contain

Tags: go

I am studying GO by using "a tour of go"
The code is doing very simple things, combine first  and last together and output on screen.
The output is a hex address instead of "aaabbb" after I run the code. Could anyone can help me out? Thank you

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Name struct{
    first,last string
}

func (name Name) fullName() string{
    return (name.first + name.last)
}

func main(){
    v := Name{"aaa","bbb"}
    fmt.Println(v.fullName)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not calling the function `fullName`. you are just passing 'the pointer' to it:
see this http://play.golang.org/p/GjibbfoyH0

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Name struct {
    first, last string
}

func (name Name) fullName() string {
    return (name.first + name.last)
}

func main() {
    v := Name{"aaa", "bbb"}
    fmt.Println(v.fullName())
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the result of the method

```
    fmt.Println(v.fullName())
```

not the address of the method

```
    fmt.Println(v.fullName)
```

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Name struct{
    first,last string
}

func (name Name) fullName() string{
    return (name.first + name.last)
}

func main(){
    v := Name{"aaa","bbb"}
    fmt.Println(v.fullName())
}
```

Output:

```
aaabbb
```